# Can a pogo pin spring cause an inductive spike?

Tags: esd, troubleshooting

I have an IO pin on a [LM3S1751](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM3S1751-IQC50-A2/726-1108-ND/1739410) microcontroller tied to a [pogo pin](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?vendor=0&keywords=829-22-008-20-001101) which shunts to ground when engaged. There is a 100k external pullup on the pin. The pin sees 3.3V when not engaged and 0V when engaged. It's really very straight forward.

Now, I've shipped approximately 100 units and recently received 4 returns because this pin always reads low/zero. I have verified that the voltage does indeed swing from 0V to 3.3V at the microcontroller. I've also verified that the registers to configure the pin as an input are set correctly using the debugger. Everything looks correct. The only way I can get the pin to read high is if I set the bit which controls the internal pullup.

Since I believe (and have had others confirm) the pin is properly configured, I am now looking at scenarios in which the pin may have been damaged. This got me wondering if exercising the pogo pin could generate a spike which may have damaged the port pin. Inside the pogo pin is a spring, which electrically looks like an inductor. However, the part of the pin that moves and the part which is static are likely always in contact which represents a parallel path. The port pin and pogo pin are separated by roughly 2 inches of 7 mil trace... not excessive.

And let's say it did somehow generate a spike that damaged the port pin. What is a likely failure mode? And would it not affect more than just the single pin on the port?

Comment: I'll second Brian [[below](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/50317/7036)] that inductive spike coming from the pogo spring is unlikely.  An ESD job from the outside sounds more plausible.  What kind of ESD protection do these lines have?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I don't actually have any ESD protection on this input because it's not exposed to the outside world where it could come into contact with a user. There are other pins that are exposed to the outside nearby (on the same pogo strip) and I am using [this part](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0603ESDA-TR1/283-2535-2-ND/686470) for protection.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without a bit more info on the layout, currents, operation etc. However, the best way to figure this out would be to see if you can generate a spike and capture it on a scope in single shot mode (shouldn't be too difficult with a DSO)

Most modern uCs have input protection, so it would have to quite a hefty spike to do damage like you mention, but it can certainly happen to just one pin and not any others.

I would try the above (even test just with a pogo pin on it's own and switch from 3.3V to 0V and monitor.

Also, is there any extra capacitance on the pin that could resonate with the inductance? What does the pin do normally - does it have standard input protection if it's an external I/O?
Posting the relevant part of the schematic would be useful (just enough to figure out any possible problems whist keeping the design private)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like inductive spikes to me.

You say a pogo pin shunts to ground when engaged, but it's not clear what is engaged with what. Speculating here : something external pushes on the moveable part of the pin, and connects to the uC's ground ...

My question is: is it remotely possible that the pin contact can happen before the ground contact, or independently of it (someone poking at the pin)?

In which case you are looking at the possibility of electrostatic damage and you can protect accordingly.